Can I restrict root user from accessing block devices directly, enforcing filesystem-only access?
Can a policy of SELinux that restricts the root user from writing data to the block devices directly (e.g. through dd command) regardless of whether they were created through the usage of mknod command or were already represented in the system in its /dev/ folder be created? Preferably without affecting system standard high-level filesystem commands (with all their due privilege checks).

SELinux is based on filesystem attributes; that doesn't apply to physical partitions.
So, no, you're barking up the wrong tree there :)
I see no problem with using any Linux Security Module (apparmor, SELinux or whatever you prefer or write) to hook and suppress mknod calls, and to remove the respective existing device nodes, and unmount sysfs. Then there'd be no way to create a device node that describes a physical device. Your system would also lose a lot of usability.
Note that through other ways, there might still be access to the underlying data structures (debugfs) that might be hard to take away from a system that still needs to do its job.
So, not a great approach. And, especially not a solution to the problem you seem to scratch in your previous question.

Restricting the usage of the command specifically, seems like half-measures here. There might be other commands that may be able to breach the security. Is there a way to identify that a certain device file belongs to a specific physical disk (so that other device representations, such as external flash drives, won't be affected) and then prevent all processes that run under root from making modifications to this file?

not the command, the syscall mknod. And you're just repeating your question here in the comment, and I already answered that above :)

What's the difference between the command and the syscall? Isnt mknod the command that runs under root user?

I'm sorry, this really exceeds the scope of what I can explain in a comment, especially if you were expecting to come up with an SELinux solution. Syscalls will be a concept that you'll need to understand, I'm afraid, so I'll let you go and read wikipedia on that :)

SELinux is based on filesystem attributes; Indeed.  But a custom LSM could very well check if the file descriptor passed to a write() system call refers to a block device and fail the write().  Now, the impacts of doing that might make the system unusable, but that's what VMs are for.  It sure seems not just possible, but maybe even trivial.

@AndrewHenle hence, what I said in the third paragraph of my answer.

@MarcusMüller I read that as an answer to the OP wanting to use SELinux, so I proposed not using SELinux but rather a custom LSM.  I don't think blocking mknod() is necessary, though, if write() calls to block devices are prevented.  I don't see a way offhand to block write() to block devices using out-of-the-box SELinux, although it's been a while since I worked on custom LSMs.  Either way, though, I wouldn't want to be the one responsible for any claim that the restriction doesn't break anything important.  Or testing it.
